# Convert Sqlite BigInt to Date

Tags: sqlite, date, bigint

I have a Sqlite database that I am using as an ado.net job store for my Quartz.net scheduler jobs.  In one table, a column called START_TIME is of type big int.

Is there a way to cast or convert a bigint to a date value?  I would like to be able to query the database to see which jobs are scheduled at what date/time and a value such as 633869892000000000 is meaningless.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

This seemed to work for me;

```
select datetime(DateColumn/10000000 - 62135596800, 'unixepoch') from YourTable
```

Credits to ; https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54282/sqlite-datetime-convert-to-net-datetime

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that `START_TIME` is the standard seconds-since-Unix-epoch, you can use:

```
select datetime(MyBigIntColumn, 'unixepoch');
```

See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html, "Modifiers" section.

Answer (score 2):

It's hundreds of nanoseconds (1 ns = 1/10^9 second) from the begining of Common Age (CA) or Christmas. 
To convert date from this format to normal date:

1. First you need to convert 633869892000000000=YourDateHundredsOfNanoSecondsCA of 100'nanoseconds to Unixepoch format (seconds since 1st of January 1970 till Your Date) by formula:

(YourDateHundredsOfNanoSecondsCA-(ROUND(1969*(365+1/4-1/100+1/400),0)-2)*24*60*60*1E9/100)*100/1E9,

where:

1.1 ROUND(1969*(365+1/4-1/100+1/400),0)-2)=DaysOf1970Years - round count of days from Jeasus born till January, 1 1970.

1.2 HundredsOfNanoSecondsOf1970Years=DaysOf1970Years*24*60*60*1E9/100 - hundreds of nanoseconds from the begining of Common Age till the begining of Unix Epoch (1st of January 1970).

1.3 YourDateInUnixEpochSeconds=(YourDateHundredsOfNanoSecondsCA-HundredsOfNanoSecondsOf1970Years)*100/1E9 - count of seconds from 01/01/1970 till Your Date.

2. Convert Unix Epoch format date to readable format by function (I give example for SQLite):

SELECT datetime(YourDateInUnixEpochSeconds, 'unixepoch');

For your example you can copy this string to SQL query editor in SQLiteStudio and run:

SELECT datetime((633869892000000000-(ROUND(1969*(365+1/4-1/100+1/400),0)-2)*24*60*60*1E9/100)*100/1E9, 'unixepoch');

and as a result you will get '2010-12-19 17:00:00'

Comment: For me this statement - SELECT datetime((DateColumn-(ROUND(1969*(365+1/4-1/100+1/400),0)-2)*24*60*60*1E9/100)*100/1E9, 'unixepoch') from YourTable; - built the dates with one year ahead. But this second statement suggested by @Gizboy seem to have worked fine (and it's also a bit more clean) - select datetime(DateColumn/10000000 - 62135596800, 'unixepoch') from YourTable;
Thank you both anyways!

Answer (score 2):

This date time is stored as Ticks. Following link covers bit more details about ticks.

[DateTime.Ticks Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8)

To convert Ticks into date time, you can use SQL query as

```
select datetime(START_TIME/10000000 - 62135596800, 'unixepoch') 
--output 2009-08-27 17:00:00
```

Ticks can be converted into DateTime as below in c sharp.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(633869892000000000); //output: 2009-08-27​T17:00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution only give me a column of empty values:

select datetime(timestmp, 'unixepoch') from logging_event

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer