# SQLite: How to convert a bigint field to date or timestamp?

Tags: sqlite

I've received a SQLite file with .db extension.
Opening it, I have a column with serial numbers: i.e. 1600414704594 (that should correspond to 2020-10-09 and whatsover time)
The db comes from outside and I don't know how that date field has been built.
Could you suggest me a query to get a valid date/time from that db column ?
I've tried reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342448/convert-sqlite-bigint-to-date) but none of the given solution returned me a valid (and actual) date, please help me.

Comment: If you chop off the 594 on the end, it's the unix timestamp for 2020-09-18 07:38:24...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Unix epoch time in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629347/how-to-convert-unix-epoch-time-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an Unix time in milliseconds. SQLite's `unixepoch` modifier expects it in seconds. The conversion is fairly easy :

```
SELECT DATETIME(1600414704594 / 1000, 'unixepoch')

2020-09-18 07:38:24
```