# Properly pass DateTime parameter to a SQLite query

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to pass a DateTime parameter to the SQLite query below:

```
var evals = await conn.QueryAsync<Evals>(@"SELECT * FROM Evaluations 
WHERE Evaluations.CompetencyScore > 1 AND Evaluations.EvaluationDate >= ? 
ORDER BY Evaluations.CandidateId", date);
```

The datatype of EvaluationDate in the PCL is DateTime, and the datatype of Evaluations.EvaluationDate in the SQLite database is bigint.

I have read and tried many different ways to do this using string literals, SQLite Date and Time functions, etc. but I haven't managed to get it right. How do I do this properly?

Comment: What do you mean it is `bigint`? Are you storing DateTime as Ticks?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: `but I haven't managed to get it right.` What _specifically_ isn't working? Is there an exception?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/1342516/34092 help?

Comment: Yes the DateTime values are stored as Ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Egads! I just discovered I had been placing single quotes around the placeholder like this **'?'** as I had seen in a few examples, once I removed them the query works. Big relief and thanks to you guys for responding, much appreciated!

Comment: That is odd, your question didn't have the quotes there.

Comment: @mjwills I was working from a couple versions of the original query and mistyped it which in the end helped me realize my mistake.